# Add a point in the map without going back to a controller or reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, grails

Good morning/afternoon/evening guys Here is the thing. I'm making a registering gsp that it actually works perfectly but what I need to do is, after a user insert the address, depending on it add a marker in the map made with the google maps api. The map actually works just fine and it has a marker already, but I put it with the longitude and latitude of my city, every register will have a different address and that marker should be that address but I just can't find the way to add it just right after inserting the address, without clicking any button or reloading the page or nothing, just after inserting. this is the code I have on the gsp:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="message(code: 'createPromo.label', default: 'CreatePromo')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false ></script>
        <g:javascript>
            var directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var directionDisplay;
            function initialize(){
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(6.20717, -75.565776);
                directionDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                var settings = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.MAP},
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas", settings);
                directionDisplay.setMap(map);
                /*var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                         '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                         '<div>'+
                         '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Qtag Technologies</h1>'+
                         '<div id="bodyContents">'+
                         '<p>Put your address here</p>'+
                         '<form id="mapping" action="#">'+
                         '<input id="start" type="text" />'+
                         '<input id="end" type="text" />'+
                         '<input type="submit" value="add point" id="hola" /></form>'+
                         '</div>'+
                         '</div>';
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString,
                    maxWidth: 300
                });*/
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: latlng
                });
                function toogleBounce(){
                    if(marker.getAnimation() != null){
                        marker.setAnimation(null);
                    }else{
                        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                    }
                }
                google.maps.even.addListener(marker, 'click', toogleBounce);
                function enviaDir(){
                    document.mapping.submit();
                }
                /*function calcRoute(){
                    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
                    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
                    var request = {
                        origin: start, 
                        destination: end,
                        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                    };
                    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
                        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
                            directionDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        }
                    });
                 }*/
                 function submitFunction(){
                     document.mapping.submit();
                 }
                 /*$("#hola").live('click', function(w){
                     w.preventDefault();
                     calcRoute(); 
                 });
              }
        </g:javascript>                                       
    <head>
    <body>
       <a href="#create-createPromo" class="skip" tabindex="1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skipt to content&hellip;" /></a>
       <div class="nav" role="navigation">
           <ul>
              <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label" /></a></li>
              <li><g:link class="list" action="list"><g:message code="defaul.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
       <div id="create-createPromo" class="content scaffold-create" role="main">
       <h1><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
       <g:if test="${flash.message}">
          <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
       </g:if>
       <g:hasErrors bean="${createPromoInstance}">
       <ul class="errors" role="alert">
           <g:eachError bean="${createPromoInstance} var="error">
               <li <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}" /></li>
           </g:eachError>
       </ul>
       </g:hasErrors>
       <g:form action="save" >
           <div id="content1" >
               <fieldset class="form">
                   <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field:'storeName', 'error')} required">
                       <label for="storeName">
                           <g:message code="createPromo.storeName.label" default="Store Name" />
                           <span class="required-indicator>*</span>
                       </label>
                       <g:textField name="storeName" value="${createPromoInstance?.storeName}" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'activity', 'error')} required">
                        <label for="activity">
                            <g:message code="createPromo.activity.label" default="Activity" />
                            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <g:select name="activity" from="${createPromoInstance.constraints.activity.inList}" value=${createPromoInstance?.activity" valueMessagePrefix="createPromo.activity" noSelection="['': '']" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'cantArt', 'error')} required">
                       <label for="cantArt">
                           <g:message code="createPromo.art.label" default="cantArt" />
                           <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                       </label>
                       <g:textField name="cantArt" value="${createPromoInstance?.cantArt}" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors (bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'art', 'error')} required" >
                        <label for="art">
                            <g:message code="createPromo.art.label" default="Art" />
                            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <g:textField name="art" value="${createPromoInstance?.art}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors (bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'wins', 'error')} ">
                        <label for="wins">
                            <g:message code="createPromo.wins.label" default="Wins" />
                            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                        </label> 
                        <g:textField name="wins" value=${createPromoInstance?.wins" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'telephone', 'error')}" >
                         <label for="telephone">
                              <g:message code="createPromo.telephone.label" default="Telephone" />
                              <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                         </label>
                         <g:textField name="telephone" value="${createPromoInstance?.telephone" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'address', 'error')}" >
                         <label for="address">
                             <g:message code="createPromo.address.label" default="Address" />
                             <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                         </label>
                         <g:textField name="address" id="address" value="${createPromoInstance?.address" onblur="initialize();" />
                     </div>
               </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div id="content2">
              <div id="map_canvas" style="width:300px; height: 200px; "></div>
          </div>
          <fieldset class="buttons">
              <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', defautl: 'Create')}" />
          </fieldset>
       </g:form>
       </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I inserted the onblur function but it doesn't help me, I don't know how to call the address and convert it into a marker, could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day I always finish answering my own questions 'cause no body helps me here! This is the code of what I did. I wanted to add a point in the map without clicking any button, just right after someone instert the address. I found some mistakes, because if I add only the number (you gotta know that my city and country is Medellín - Colombia) it puts the marker in somewhere else but not in my country. So I had to add 2 more boxes for selecting the city and country (It will change later, adding more cities and countries, for now it just have one city and one country), and now it works perfectly. Well, now here is the code for you guys if you need it! Hope it will be useful for anyone. :)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message (code: 'createPromo.label', default: 'CreatePromo')}" /> 
        <title><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no" />
        <script type="text/javascript src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ></script>
        <g:javascript>
              var map;
              var geocoder;
              function initialize(){
                  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(6.20717, -75.565776);
                  var settings = {
                      zoom: 15,
                      center: latlng,
                      mapTypeControl: true,
                      mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                      navigationControl: true,
                      navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                  };
                  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
              }
              function codeAddress(){
                  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
                  var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
                  var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
                  geocoder.geocode({'address': address + ' ' + city + ' - ' + country}, function(results, status){
                      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                           map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                           var maker = new google.maps.Marker({
                               map: map,
                               position: results[0].geometry.location                               
                           });
                      }else{
                           alert ("Geocoder was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                      }
                  });
              }
        </g:javascript>                   
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#create-createPromo" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;" /></a>
        <div class="nave" role="navigation">
            <ul>
               <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}><g:message code="default.home.label" /></a></li>
               <li><g:link class="list" action="list"><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="create-createPromo" class="content scaffold-create" role="main">
            <h1><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}" >
               <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <g:hasErrors bean="{createPromoInstance}">
            <ul class="errors" role="alert">
                <g:eachError bean="${createPromoInstance} var="error">
                    <li <g:if test="{error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id=${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}" /></li>
                </g:eachError>
            </ul>
            </g:hasErrors>
            <g:form action="save">
                 <fieldset class="form">
                     <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'storeName', 'error')} ">
                          <label for="storeName">
                              <g:message code="createPromo.storeName.label" default="Store Name" />
                          </label>
                          <g:textField name="storeName" value="${createPromoInstance?.storeName}" id="storeName" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'activity', 'error')} ">
                         <label for="activity">
                             <g:message code="createPromo.activity.label default="Activity" />
                         </label>
                         <g:select name="activity" from="${createPromoInstance.constraints.activity.inList}" value="${createPromoInstance?.activity}" valueMessagePrefix="createPromo.activity" noSelection="['':'']" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'cantArt', 'error')} required">
                          <label for="canArt">
                              <g:message code="createPromo.canArt.label" default="cantArt" />
                              <span class="required-indicator>*</span>
                          </label>
                          <g:textField name="cantArt" value="${createPromoInstance?.cantArt" id="cantArt" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field:'art', 'error')} ">
                          <label for="art">
                              <g:message code="createPromo.art.label" default="Art" />
                          </label>
                          <g:textField name="art" value="${createPromoInstance?.art" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'wins', 'error' )} ">
                          <label for="wins">
                              <g:message code="createPromo.wins.label" default="Wins" />
                          </label>
                          <g:textField name="wins" value="${createPromoInstance?.wins}" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'telephone', 'error')}" >
                          <label for="telephone">
                              <g:message  code="createPromo.telephone.label" default="Telephone" />
                          </label>
                          <g:textField name="telephone" value="${createPromoInstance?.telephone}" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="fielcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'city', 'error')} ">
                          <label for="city">
                              <g:message code="createPromo.city.label" default="City" />
                          </label>
                          <g:select name="city" id="city" from="${createPromoInstance.constraints.city.inList}" value="${createPromoInstance?.city}" valueMessagePrefix="createPromo.city" nonSelection="['':'']" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'country', 'error' })" >
                          <label for="country">
                               <g:message code="createPromo.country.label" defuatl="Country" />
                          </label>
                          <g:select name="country" id="country" from="${createPromoInstance.constraints.country,inList}" value="${createPromoInstance?.country}" valueMessagePrefix="createPromo.country" nonSelection="['':'']" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: createPromoInstance, field: 'address', 'error' })" >
                          <lable for="address">
                               <g:message code="createPromo.address.label" default="Address" />
                          </label>
                          <g:textField name="address" id="address" value="${createPromoInstance?.address}" onblur="codeAddress()" />
                     </div>
                     <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; ></div>  
                 </fieldset>
            </g:form>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```